# How to control test grouping in parallel mode

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have groups of tests, lets say groupA, groupB, groupC and groupD.
I want to launch these tests in parallel but I need to have control over which group launched in which worker. For instance, I want groupA and groupC to be launched in workerA, groupB and groupD in workerB. Is there a way to do this with jest?